# Result of a SQL table on a single line (SQLServer)

Tags: sql

My SQL table (TOTAL_PAR_STATUT) contains the following fields:

DISTRIBUTEUR_ID -- receptionDate -- STATUS_CHAMP_ID -- TOTAL_BY_STATUS

When I execute the query:

```
SELECT tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID,
   tps.receptionDate,
   tps.STATUS_CHAMP_ID,
   tps.TOTAL_BY_STATUS
FROM TOTAL_PAR_STATUT tps
WHERE tps.receptionDate between '06-10-2013 00:00:00' AND '06-10-2013 23:59:59'
       AND tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID = 1 
       AND STATUS_CHAMP_ID IN (1,2,3,9,10,11,7)
GROUP BY tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID, tps.receptionDate, tps.TOTAL_BY_STATUS, tps.STATUS_CHAMP_ID;
```

It gives me the following result:

```
 DISTRIBUTEUR_ID --- receptionDate --- STATUS_CHAMP_ID --- TOTAL_BY_STATUS

     1   ---    '2013-10-06 00:00:00' --- 3  ---            1

     1   ---    '2013-10-06 00:00:00' --- 1  ---            13
```

I want to group the result in a single line to give me the following:

```
     DISTRIBUTEUR_ID --- receptionDate --- TOTAL_WHERE_STATUS_3 --- TOTAL_WHERE_STATUS_1

         1  --- '2013-10-06 00:00:00'   ---  1 ---                  13
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM(CASE WHEN ...)

This is not tested but should give you and idea of how to get what you want:

```
SELECT tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID,
   tps.receptionDate,
   SUM(CASE WHEN tps.STATUS_CHAMP_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[TOTAL_WHERE_STATUS_3],
   SUM(CASE WHEN tps.STATUS_CHAMP_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[TOTAL_WHERE_STATUS_1],
FROM TOTAL_PAR_STATUT tps
WHERE tps.receptionDate between '06-10-2013 00:00:00' AND '06-10-2013 23:59:59'
       AND tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID = 1 
       AND STATUS_CHAMP_ID IN (1,2,3,9,10,11,7)
GROUP BY tps.DISTRIBUTEUR_ID, tps.receptionDate
```